# все привет !помогите)не работает импорт Beautifulsoup в питоне .не высвечивается и поэтому мой код видимо не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS:


    def get_response(url):
        response = requests.get()
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.text
        else:
            return "Не успешный запрос "

    my_url = "сюда написала сайт который мне нужен"
    print(get_response(my_url))
```

Comment: Значит он не установлен для используемого интерпретатора.
pip install beautifulsoup4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во второй строчке не должно быть двоеточия

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


    def get_response(url):
        response = requests.get()
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.text
        else:
            return "Не успешный запрос "

    my_url = "сюда написала сайт который мне нужен"
    print(get_response(my_url))
```